# Fourier series representation and the first coefficient

Tags: fourier-series

So, if we represent a function of time using Fourier series:
$$f(t)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg[{a_n\cos{(n\omega_0t)}+b_n\sin{(n\omega_0t)}}\bigg]$$
what is the point of that halved first coefficient? Couldn't it simply be written as:
$$f(t)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg[{a_n\cos{(n\omega_0 t)}+b_n\sin{(n\omega_0 t)}}\bigg]$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is done so that the same formula can be used for all values of $n$:
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\cos(n\,t)\,dt,\quad n\ge0.
$$
Otherwise, the definition of $a_0$ should be
$$
a_0=\frac{1}{2\,\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\,dt.
$$